# How should we deal with multiple questions per question?

Tags: support, faq, vote-to-close

In particular new users sometimes ask a question that contains multiple subquestions which are better off as separate questions.

- How can we identify when such a question is too broad?
- How should experienced users deal with this?

Comment: The irony in this question is anything but lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## When are multiple questions a problem?

A few rules of thumb:

- Questions should only be asked together if their answers (if asked separately) can be expected to strongly overlap.
  Otherwise, they should be split.
- Answers to a question should be directly comparable, and thus it should not happen that there is a best answer to one subquestion and another best answer to another subquestion.
  In the latter case, they should be split.
- If you can answer only one subquestion to a question, it should be split.
- If a question is asking to identify multiple fonts, styles, etc., it should be split.

In general, do not be overcautious with this:
If you think that a question is better off as two separate questions, you are very likely right.

## How to react?

#### If the question is unanswered

If there is at least one subquestion that is not closeworthy for other reasons, **edit it immediately** (or suggest an edit, if you do not have the reputation).
There is nothing to be gained from waiting for the asker or others to perform the edit – it only increases the risk that somebody answers the question in the meantime.

Select the surviving subquestion by the following criteria (in order of priority):

- Do not select a question that is clearly or borderline closeworthy.
- Is there a primary question that the asker is most concerned about?
- Is there a question that is best asked before the others?
- Which question are you most likely to upvote?

Leave a comment explaining what you did, e.g., as follows:

> As this site follows a strict question-and-answer format, there should be only one distinct question per question.
>     I therefore took the liberty to remove your second question; feel free to ask it separately.

#### If the question has answers

- If all answers address the same subquestion, edit the question immediately to contain only that subquestion.
  Leave a comment similar as above.
- In all other cases, you have to make a judgement call: Can this be resolved with a few minor edits and without invalidating large parts of existing answers? If not, vote to close as *too broad.* Leave a comment explaining your choice and possibly encourage the asker to narrow down their question. Keep in mind though that somebody answering a case of multiple questions per question has to accept the risk of their answer being invalidated by edits to the question.